# Function pointers and C++ templates

Tags: c++, c, templates, function, pointers

I have a C++ code and i really need to use C function in it:

```
int procedure(... , S_fp fun , ...)
```

where fun - is a pointer to function which signature must be like that:

```
int fun(double* , double* , double)
```

The function, pointer to which i want to use, is a member of a class template:

```
template<int nPar> class PenaltyAlgorithm
{
public:
...
int Calculate(double* param, double* val, double prec)
{
   ...
}
...
}
```

As you can see, its signature is in order. But when I do this:
procedure(... &PenaltyAlgorithm::Calculate, ...);

I get error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘int (PenaltyAlgorithm<30>::*)(double*, double*, double)’ to ‘int (*)(...)’ for argument ...
```

Please, help. If you need any additional info, please, write.

Thanks!!!

After reading answers, i understood that it's important to add information about class:

```
template<int nPar> class PenaltyAlgorithm
{
public:
int Calculate(double* param, double* val, double prec)
    {
    *val = comp_fun->Compute(param);
    }

double* RunAlgorithm()
    {
        ...
        procedure(... &PenaltyAlgorithm<nPar>::Calculate, ...);
        ... 
    }
...
private:
...
CompositeFunction<nPar>* comp_fun;
}
```

1). I can't use static fun, because this fun need to get access to members of class;

2). Can we use the fact, that we call 'procedure' from fun-member of class?

Comment: Calling a function on a class passes a implicit this pointer so your signature is obviously wrong.  You should read [the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)

Answer (score 3):

Calculate is a non-static method on PenaltyAlgorithm.  It requires an instance of the PenaltyAlgorithm to execute, so it can't be fed to a C function as a plain function pointer.

Can the Calculate function be made static?  If it can, it should work the same as a C function pointer, only it won't be able to access non-static data in the PenaltyAlgorithm class.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `int Calculate(double* param, double* val, double prec)` as an instance member has a hidden `this` pointer, that a global function or static member won't have. Without this, it won't know which `PenaltyAlgorithm` to run it on.

Either the pointer should be of type `int (PenaltyAlgorithm::*)(double* param, double* val, double prec)` or `Calculate` should be static.

Answer (score 1):

If `int procedure(... , S_fp fun , ...)` must definitely be a C function, then there is no way to do what you are looking for directly. If you try to pass a class member function pointer it will have a hidden this pointer as its first argument in the stack, hence the prototypes won't match.

However you can create a global or static function which internally uses a saved instance pointer to access the `PenaltyAlgorithm` class indirectly. 
You can try the below:

1) Save the instance pointer of the class you want to pass to the `procedure` function to a global variable.

2) Create a new global function `int CalculateGlobal(double* param, double* val, double prec)`

3) Pass the `CalculateGlobal` function's pointer as the function pointer to your `procedure` function.

4) CalculateGlobal function can then use the saved instance pointer to access the specific class' internals.

Well this is not a good way of doing things of course...

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a pointer like that to a member function unless it is a static member function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `Calculate` static, use

```
static int Calculate(double* param, double* val, double prec)
```

instead of

```
int Calculate(double* param, double* val, double prec)
```